# Doubt on Laurent series of $f(z) = 1/z(z-2)^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, laurent-series

I've a doubt about this exercise

> Find the Laurent series of the function $$f(z) = \frac{1}{z(z-2)^2}$$ addend $z=0$ in the annular regions of interest

The problem it's not totally about the how to evaluate it, but instead about the fact that *using two different methods* I get *two different Laurent series*. Let me explain my thought.

First my question is only about the "first" region $|z|<2$.

### Fist method

With some algebraic manipulations on the series I get that $$f(z) = \frac{1}{z}\frac{1}{(z-2)^2} = \frac{1}{z}\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{-1}{z-2}\right) =  \frac{1}{z}\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{1}{2-z}\right)\\ =  \frac{1}{z}\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{1}{2(1-\frac{z}{2})}\right) = \frac{1}{2z}\frac{d}{dz}\color{red}{\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{2}}\right)}$$ The red factor it's just a geometric series because $$|z|\lt 2 \implies \left|\frac{z}{2}\right|\lt 1$$ Using this fact what I get is $$f(z) = \frac{1}{2z}\frac{d}{dz}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left({z\over 2}\right)^n$$ bringing the derivative into the sum I finally get the result $$f(z) = \frac{1}{2z}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{d}{dz}\left({z\over 2}\right)^n = \frac{1}{4z}\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\left({z\over 2}\right)^{n-1} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{nz^{n-1}}{2^{n+1}}$$ and this, according to Wolfram, is the right result.

### Second method

Taking the derivation from the third step of the method before I've done different algebraic manipulations, mainly $$f(z) = \frac{1}{z}\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{1}{2-z}\right) = \frac{1}{z}\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{1}{2-z\color{blue}{+1-1}}\right) = \frac{1}{z}\frac{d}{dz}\color{red}{\left(\frac{1}{1-(z-1)}\right)}$$ again the red factor **should**, I explain in a moment, be a geometric series because $$|z|\lt 2\implies z-1\lt 1\tag 1$$ taking this for good I continue with the calculations $$f(z) = \frac{1}{z}\frac{d}{dz}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (z-1)^n = \frac{1}{z}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{d}{dz}(z-1)^n = \frac{1}{z}\sum_{n=1}^\infty n(z-1)^{n-1}$$ I'm stopping here because this **doesn't seem, to me, the same as before!**

The questions then are:

> **Question 1**: Why are they not the same? Where is the wrong assumption?
>
> **Question 2**: Is it wrong to assume $(1)$?
>
> **Question 3**: If there's nothing wrong, which I doubt it, how can I go from the second series to the first with some algebraic manipulations?

Comment: What's the meaning of $z-1<1$? After all, $z$ is a complex number.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos That's true! But even if I say that $$|z-1|<1$$ this wouldn't be totally wrong, would it?

Comment: The second is a Laurent series centered at $z=1$, not centered at $z=0$ as the question asked for.

Comment: @DanielSchepler This makes a lot of sense.....

Comment: Yes, it would. Take $z=-\frac32$. Then $\lvert z\rvert<2$, but $\left\lvert z-1\right\rvert\geqslant 1$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos That's right! Now I understand, thank you very much to both of you! Really appreciate it

Comment: I'm glad I could help.